# Set specific scientific notation in python

Tags: python, precision, scientific-notation

I have the following number:

```
1.198343100927212e-08
```

But I want to represent it as

```
11.98343100927212e-09   # I want to set the units at *nano...*
11983.43100927212e-12   # I want to set the units at *pico...*
0.01198343100927212e-06 # I want to set the units at *micro...*
```

How can I change and set to a specific scientific notation numbers in python?

Answer (score 2):

You can display the scaled float:

```py
def repr_float(x, exponent):
    return f'{x * 10**-exponent:f}e{exponent}'
```

The `:f` in the format specifier is to prevent the float from being displayed as a scientific notation itself. You can also specify an arbitrary precision, `:.20f` for example, if you want to show more digits.

This gives:

```py
>>> a = 1.198343100927212e-08
>>> repr_float(a, -6)
'0.011983e-6'
>>> repr_float(a, -9)
'11.983431e-9'
>>> repr_float(a, -12)
'11983.431009e-12'
>>> eval(repr_float(a, -12))  # don't actually do this, but you can plug it right back in and it will give you the same number
1.1983431009e-08
```